# Streaming pulseaudio to VLC via null sink

Tags: vlc-media-player, pulse-audio

I'm attempting to create a HTTP audio stream via pulseaudio and VLC:

```
cvlc -vvv pulse://alsa_output.pci-0000_00_05.0.analog-stereo.monitor --sout '#transcode{acodec=vorbis,ab=128,channels=2}:standard{access=http,dst=0.0.0.0:8888/audio.ogg}'
```

This works fine, however I don't want the audio to be played on the host. I can stop the audio being played be setting up a null sink but I can't get this null sink to be streamed by VLC.

For example if I set up a null sink called fake and run the command:

```
cvlc -vvv pulse://fake --sout '#transcode{acodec=vorbis,ab=128,channels=2}:standard{access=http,dst=0.0.0.0:8888/audio.ogg}'
```

I get:

```
[0x7f03184cc1d8] pulsesrc demux error: cannot connect record stream: No such entity
[0x7f03184cc1d8] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[0x7f0314003f58] main input debug: creating access 'pulse' location='fake', path='(null)'
[0x7f03184cc1d8] main access debug: looking for access module matching "pulse": 25 candidates
[0x7f03184cc1d8] main access debug: no access modules matched
[0x7f0314003f58] main input error: open of `pulse://fake' failed
[0x7f0314003f58] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[0x7f0314003f58] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'pulse://fake'. Check the log for details.
```

Is there some way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

**fake** is your null sink (audio destination)

**fake.monitor** is monitor of fake (listening source)

You want to use **fake.monitor** as source.

```
cvlc -vvv pulse://fake.monitor --sout '#transcode{acodec=vorbis,ab=128,channels=2}:standard{access=http,dst=0.0.0.0:8888/audio.ogg}'
```